# m out of n bootstrap implementation in R

Tags: r, bootstrap, extreme-value

I am wishing to estimate the sampling distribution of an extreme order statistic (the sample maximum). The usual nonparametric (n-out-of-n) bootstrap fails miserably in this case.

Chernick (2011) recommends the m-out-of-n bootstrap as a remedy.

What I've done is employ the delta method to come up with an approximation of the standard error of my estimator of interest in order to form a large-sample confidence interval under the assumption of asymptotic normality. I fear however that my resulting interval may be too narrow and would now like to compare it with a confidence interval generated from the m/n bootstrap.

There doesn't seem to be an m-out-of-n bootstrap method available in the 'boot' R package. Does anyone know if there is another package to carry this out?

Comment: Is your question only about R package/code? If yes, it would be off topic. Otherwise, could you edit to tell us what kind of help do you need?

Comment: @Tim: I disagree. The question IMO "needs statistical expertise to understand or answer", which is a direct quote from [our on-topic help page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @StephanKolassa I didn't vote to close it, I'm just asking for clarification.

Comment: @Tim Most literature I've come across delves into the theory behind the m/n bootstrap, which I understand. I have yet to find a user-friendly implementation of it in R though, which is why I pose the question.

Comment: @Tim: I know you didn't VTC. You write "it would be off-topic", which I disagree with, and I wanted to note this before someone else sees that statement with a diamond next to the user name and jumps to close-vote...

Comment: Bootstrapping is easy to implement in R. If you can at least point to some literature, it's hopefully no more than a few lines of code. That said, your approach seems iffy. The maximum/minimum in *most* cases does not have an asymptotic normal distribution. The power of the bootstrap is being agnostic to the sampling distribution of the test statistic. Have you tried a double bootstrap?

Comment: @AdamO This work from 1997 is widely cited with numerous examples of the nonparametric bootstrap's failure in deriving quantities for extreme order statistics: http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/a7n11.pdf. Regarding a double bootstRap, I tried yet.

Comment: R [Distillery](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/distillery/distillery.pdf) package allows for m < n bootstrap resampling.

Comment: What is the motivation for wanting to know the sampling distribution?  Would an exact Bayesian approach be helpful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the m-out-of-n bootstrap will most likely (or: almost surely ;-) work in your case because it is known to be more robust than the usual bootstrap and thus works under much weaker conditions:

> Bickel, Götze, van Zwet: "Resampling fewer than n observations: gains,
> losses, and remedies for losses." Statistica Sinica 7 (1997), 1-31

Actually, your particular example is given as a case when the traditional (n-out-of-n) bootstrap fails in the above paper. Another advantage of the m-out-of-n bootstrap is that it can be used *without replacement* and thus does not introduce a considerable amount of ties into continuous distributions for which ties are impossible.

A problem with the m-out-of-n bootstrap, however, is that it requires knowledge of a rescaling factor $\tau_n$ which is necessary for constructing the confidence intervals. According to

> P. Bertail, D. N. Politis, J. P. Romano: "On subsampling estimators with unknown rate of convergence,” Journal of the American Statistical Association, vol. 94, no. 446, pp. 569–579, 1999,

$\tau_n$ must be chosen such that such that $\tau_n^2 \operatorname{Var}(T)$ converges to some constant V, so you can simulate some data for your statistic with varying sample size $n$ and have a look at the convergence rate of the variance. (Remark: Bertail et al. also suggested a method to estimate $\tau_n$ by another bootstrap, but when I tried it, I found this method to be grossly inaccurate, so it should be taken with a grain of salt).

The *destillery* package mentioned by @laiguanasupersonica supports $m<n$ in the function `booter()`, but, alas, it has a bug which prevents the choice `replace=FALSE`. Moreover, the function `destillery::ci.booted()` reports the confidence intervals as *character strings*, which makes it awkward to use, and it does not provide support for introducing a scaling factor $\tau_n$.

It is thus easiest to implement it yourself as described in section 5 of the following article (for ready-to-run R code, see listing 1):

> Dalitz, Arning, Goebbels: "A Simple Bias Reduction for Chatterjee's Correlation." https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.15496 (2023)

Another inconvenience of the m-out-of-n bootstrap is that it has a parameter $m$ that must be chosen, which will depend on $n$. For asymptotic convergence of the (rescaled!) bootstrap distribution to the true distribution, it must be of the form $m(n)\to\infty$ and $m(n)/n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ (proven by Politis & Romano, 1994), but this still leaves plenty of of options. The sample code from listing 1 in the above paper uses $m=2\sqrt{n}$, because it worked best for the particular statistic of interest. Swanepool derived from a Monte Carlo study for a different estimator the rule of thumb $m=2n/3$, but this was based on very weak grounds: Only two simulations with $n=15$ and $n=30$, and these simulations already showed a tendency that the coverage probability for the choice $m=2n/3$ falls below the nominal level as $n$ increases. This should be expected, because the choice $m=2n/3$ violates the condition $m/n\to 0$.

> Swanepoel: "A note on proving that the (modified) bootstrap works."
> Communications in Statistics-Theory and Methods 15.11 (1986): 3193-3203.

The simplest method to estimate $m$ from the data seems to be the method by Götze & Račkauskas, but this requires an additional bootstrap for minimizing the distance between two empirical cumulative distribution functions for the choices $m$ and $m/2$:

> Götze, Račkauskas: "Adaptive choice of bootstrap sample sizes."
> Lecture Notes-Monograph Series (2001): 286-309.